# Why does a Community Wiki post remove the tag counts?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

When a post is turned into a Community Wiki post the original author loses the tag count values for the tags (i.e., a "python" post with 50 upvotes gives +50 in the 'Tags' profile section for "python"). But this gain is lost when the post is turned into Community Wiki.

Why is this the case?

According to [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts):

> The original author still gets badges based on community posts.

But this is not possible for class badges which are earned based on tag counts (bronze, silver and gold depending on how many upvotes one has in a tag). If someone has multiple great answers for certain tags and they are each turned into Community Wiki posts then that person is back to zero (in this extend).

I think we should have:

- The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
- The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.

but also:

- The original author keeps the tag counts gained before their post entered community mode.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the tag badges don't consider CW posts. What is said is correct: The user who created a CW post still gain badges, if the badge is not defined to exclude CW posts.

For example, a CW post still gives to the user who created it the following badges:

- Disciplined
- Good Answer
- Good Question
- Great Answer
- Great Question
- Peer Pressure
- Nice Answer
- Nice Question
- Notable Question

The tag badges are badges that are removed when the conditions necessary to gain them are not anymore met. For example, if you delete three of your answers and the number of answers you gave for a specific tag gets lower than twenty, then you lose the bronze badge for that tag. As the requirements include also the post not being a CW, it makes sense to me remove tag badges when a post is made CW, or not counting anymore the score for those posts became CW.

Comment: That makes sense but the upvotes were earned while the post was not yet a CW. My viewpoint is that they should still be kept in the tag counts. Any votes that are gained/lost when the post is CW should not contribute to the badge of course.